# Error bounds for non-autonomous systems with respect to input

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, error-propagation

The error bounds for an ordinary differential equation:
\begin{equation}
  \dot{x}(t) = f(x(t))
\end{equation}
with respect to initial conditions $x(t_0) = x_0$, $\hat{x}(t_0)=\hat{x}_0$
\begin{equation}
  \left|\left|\hat{x}(t)-x(t)\right|\right| \leqslant e^{L\left|t-t_0\right|}\left|\left|\hat{x}(0)-x(0)\right|\right|
\end{equation}
where L is a Lipschitz constant of $f$ with respect to $x$. For a proof, see e.g. [Stoer, Bulirsch](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387954523).

I have read in an article [[Arnold](http://www.springer.com/in/book/9783662449257)] that for a system: 
\begin{equation}
  \dot{x}(t) = f(x(t), u(t))
\end{equation}
hold a similar bounds with respect to different input signals $u(t)$ and $\tilde{u}(t)$:
\begin{equation}
  \left|\left|\tilde{x}(t)-x(t)\right|\right| \leqslant C\left(e^{L\left|t-t_0\right|}-1\right)\max_{s\in[t_0,t]}\left|\left|\tilde{u}(s)-u(s)\right|\right|
\end{equation}
where L is a Lipschitz constant of $f$ with respect to $x$. Initial conditions are assumed to be equal $\tilde{x}(0) = x(0) = x_0$. An input signal $\tilde{u}(t)$ is assumed to be a polynomial approximation of $u(t)$.

I would like to ask for a help with proving this statement. I went through the following steps:
\begin{align}
  &x(t) = x_0 + \int^t_{t_0}f(x(s), u(s)) \mathrm{ds}\\
  &\tilde{x}(t) = x_0 + \int^t_{t_0}f(\tilde{x}(s), \tilde{u}(s)) \mathrm{ds}\\
  &\tilde{x}(t) - x(t) = \int^t_{t_0} \left[f(\tilde{x}(s), \tilde{u}(s)) - f(x(s), u(s)) \right] \mathrm{ds}\\
  &\left|\left|\tilde{x}(t) - x(t)\right|\right| \leqslant \int^t_{t_0} \left|\left|f(\tilde{x}(s), \tilde{u}(s)) - f(x(s), u(s)) \right|\right| \mathrm{ds}
\end{align}
I get stuck at this step. I am not sure whether I am supposed to use Lipschitz condition:
\begin{equation}
  \left|\left|f(\tilde{x}(t), U(t)) - f(x(t), U(t)) \right|\right| \leqslant L\left|\left|\tilde{x}(t) - x(t)\right|\right| 
\end{equation}
and whether this is a correct formulation of Lipschitz condition with respect to x or whether I need to somehow use the fact about polynomial approximation. Any assistance is appreciated.

Edit:
Additional uniform Lipschitz condition of $f$ with respect to both arguments can be assumed.

Comment: I can prove it if $f$ is Lipschitz in the second argument ($u$'s one) uniformly with respect the first. Is that sufficient for your purposes ?

Comment: @MahmoudAbdelrazek Yes, it is, I can adapt the question to the answer. I was a bit fuzzy in this part and any additional assumptions are welcome, especially the reasonable one like Lipschitz condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Gronwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality#Integral_form_for_continuous_functions), we need only the following corollary,

> Let $L$ and $U$ be non-negative real numbers. Suppose that$\ \ f: [t_0,t_1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function satisfying
>   $$f(t) \leq \int_{t_0}^{t} Lf(t)+M \ \,dt  $$ 
>   Then 
>   $$f(t) \leq \frac{L}{M} \left(\exp(t-t_0) -1\right)$$

*proof.*

From Grownwall's inequality:

$$\begin{align}
f(t) & \leq  M(t-t_0) + \int_{t_0}^{t} ML(s-a)\exp\left(\int_{s}^{t}L\,dr\right) \, ds\\
& =  M(t-t_0) + \int_{a}^{t} ML(s-t_0)\exp\left(M(t-s)\right) \, ds \\
& = M(t-t_0) + \left[-M(s-t_0)\exp(L(t-s))\right]_{t_0}^{t} + \int_{t_0}^{t} M\exp(L(t-s)) \,dt \\
&= \frac{M}{L} \left(\exp(t-t_0) -1\right)\
\end{align} $$
Now we prove

> Let $f \in C(\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^m, \mathbb{R})$ be lipschitz in the first variable with constant $L$, and in the second variable by constant $M$. If $x_i:[t_0,t_1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfy, 
>   $$\begin{cases}
> x_i'(t) = f(x_i(t),u_i(t)\\
> x_i(t) = x_0\\
> \end{cases}$$
>   Then there is a constant depending only on $L$ and $M$ s.t,
>   $$\|x_1(T)-x_2(T)\| \leq C\left(  e^{L(T-t_0)}-1 \right) \max_{[t_0,T]} \|u_2(t) - u_1(t) \| $$
>   for all $T \in [t_0,t_1]$

*proof.*

Let $T \in [t_0,t_1]$. Note that for all $t \leq T$,

$$\|x_1(t) - x_2(t)\| \leq \int_{t_0}^{t} \|f(x_1(t),u_1(t)) - f(x_2(t),u_2(t))\| \,dt$$

By Lipschitz continuity:

$$\begin{align}
\|x_1(t) - x_2(t) \| & \leq \int_{t_0}^{t} L\|x_1(t) - x_2(t)\| + \|f(x_2(t),u_1(t)) - f(x_2(t),u_2(t)) \| \,dt \\
& \leq \int_{t_0}^{t} L\|x_1(t) - x_2(t)\| + M\max_{[t_0,T]} \|u_2(t) - u_1(t) \| \,dt \\
\end{align}$$

Hence by Gronwall's inequality (take $f(t) = \|x_2(t) -x_1(t) \|$ and replact $M$ in the corollary above by $M\max_{[t_0,T]} \|u_2(t) - u_1(t) \|$):

$$ \|x_1(T)-x_2(T)\| \leq \frac{M}{L} \left(  e^{L(T-t_0)}-1 \right) \max_{[t_0,T]} \|u_2(t) - u_1(t) \|  $$

Comment: I am a little bit unclear about the definition of Lipschitz function in two variables. I don't think it matches what I wrote in the question. It seems that $ \|f(x_1(t),u_1(t)) - f(x_2(t),u_2(t))\| \leqslant L\|x_1(t) - x_2(t)\| + \|f(x_2(t),u_1(t)) - f(x_2(t),u_2(t))\| \leqslant L\|x_1(t) - x_2(t)\| + M\max_{[t_0,T]} \|u_2(t) - u_1(t) \| $. Can you provide a reference or a little more explanation for this part?

Comment: What I meant by Lipschitz in first variable is:

$$\|f(x_1,t) - f(x_2,t) \| \leq L\| x_1(t) -x_2(t) \| $$

and in second variable:

$$\|f(x,u_1)-f(x,u_2) \| \leq M ||u_2 - u_1 \| $$

This true for example if $f$ is differentiable (mean value theorem in several variables)

Comment: If I got it right \begin{align} \| f(x_1, u_1) - f(x_2, u_2) \| &= \| f(x_1, u_1) - f(x_2, u_1)+ f(x_1, u_1) - f(x_2, u_2) \| \\ &\leqslant  \| f(x_1, u_1) - f(x_2, u_1) \|+ \| f(x_2, u_1) - f(x_2, u_2) \| \\ &\leqslant  L\| x_1 - x_2 \|+ M \| u_2  -  u_1 \|\\ \end{align} follows from the triangle inequality. Is the max necessary? I took it from the article, but I am not sure if it can be avoided.